# jQuery animation mess when trying to animate multiple elements at the same time

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to fade out an div (with an image inside) and fade in a div (with text inside) at the same time. So there is some kind of transition effect. But when i'm moving the cursor too fast over multiple divs, some fade in, some fade out and in the end some are still invisible.

**Styling**

```
.portfolio-thumbnail-detail {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    display: none;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="span5 portfolio-item" title="<?php echo $portfolio->ID; ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $portfolio->guid ?>">
    <div class="portfolio-thumbnail" id="portfolio-thumbnail-<?php echo $portfolio->ID; ?>">
        <img src="image.png">
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-thumbnail-detail" id="portfolio-thumbnail-detail-<?php echo $portfolio->ID; ?>">
        Text
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('.portfolio-item').hover(function() {
    var id = -1;
    var image, detail;

    id = $(this).attr('title');
    image = $('#portfolio-thumbnail-'+id);
    detail = $('#portfolio-thumbnail-detail-'+id);
    detail.css('opacity', 0);
    detail.show();

    $(image).animate({
        opacity: 0,
    }, {
        duration: 400,
        step: function(now, fx) {
            detail.css('opacity', 1-now);
        },
        complete: function() {
            image.hide();
        },
    });
}, function() {
    var id = -1;
    var image, detail;

    id = $(this).attr('title');
    image = $('#portfolio-thumbnail-'+id);
    detail = $('#portfolio-thumbnail-detail-'+id);
    image.css('opacity', 0);
    image.show();

    $(detail).animate({
        opacity: 0,
    }, {
        duration: 400,
        step: function(now, fx) {
            image.css('opacity', 1-now);
        },
        complete: function() {
            detail.hide();
        },
    });
});
});
```

**Possible Solution**

I found another solution. I call a *reset()* function at the beginning of the hover function and in the complete event of the "hover-out" function.

> function reset() {
>   $('.portfolio-thumbnail').css('opacity', 1);
>   $('.portfolio-thumbnail-detail').css('opacity', 0);
>   }

That looks ok to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to stop the cued animations with `stop()`

```
 $(image).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0,
    }, {
        duration: 400,
        step: function(now, fx) {
            detail.css('opacity', 1-now);
        },
        complete: function() {
            image.hide();
        },
    });
```